# response.body() returned from splash:html() does not look like HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to parse the HTML of a website using scrapy and splash. My main lua function return statement looks like return splash:html() and then I am trying to parse the HTML in my def parse(self, response) function. However, all my response.css and response.xpath are returning None and empty lists. Also, I am noticing that the HTML looks weird (contains several html code tags, json objects, no classes, no ids...). I guess splash:html() does not return like an actual response.body that looks like HTML. I can see the docs mentioning a lua binary object that somehow must be converted to a lua string, but that is not working for me either.
Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es" class="theme theme--mercado"><head>
    <script type="application/javascript">!function(i,n){void 0!==i.addEventListener&&void 0!==i.hidden&&(n.liVisibilityChangeListener=function(){i.hidden&&(n.liHasWindowHidden=!0)},i.addEventListener("visibilitychange",n.liVisibilityChangeListener))}(document,window);</script>
    <title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/c36v9h7vs5uekvaupu8c54vij">
<meta name="__init" content="{&quot;routingLix&quot;:{&quot;engines&quot;:{&quot;profile&quot;:{&quot;lixKey&quot;:&quot;voyager.web.profile-tetris&quot;,&quot;lixedEngine&quot;:
[{"sourceType":"PROFILE_PICTURE","*miniProfile":"urn:li:fs_miniProfile:ACoAACngMAEBuHRFEFa9VFBZIh_f3zof_DiuAcA","$type":"com.voyager.common.ImageAttribute"}],"$type":"com.voyager.common.ImageViewModel"},"supplementaryActorInfo":{"textDirection":"USER_LOCALE","text":" • 3er y demás","$type":"com.voyager.common.TextViewModel"},"name":{"textDirection":"FIRST_STRONG","attributes":
```

Comment: Please add your spider and settings codes

Comment: Usual settings from scrapy and splash properly configured. The reason behind the weirdness of the code snippet above is because the page is in a loading state with a UI spinner. However, even increasing wait times and timeouts it keeps loading forever. Trying in the docker container with the simplest lua script possible returns HTTPError #999 Failed loading page 
My script performs login, splash:go("..."), splash:wait(20) and then returns {html = splash:html()}